# Vecotorized Lookback with Two Numpy Arrays

Tags: python, numpy

Is it possible to vectorize lookbacks using two Numpy arrays? In example one below I need to "loop" through each value in first_arr and check if any of the previous 4 values contain 3 or more values from second_arr. If the condition is true the value in first_arr should be added to result_arr.

If there are fewer than 4 values in first_arr it should check however many values exist (although obviously the condition will never be true if less than 3).

The actual arrays will be much larger so I am looking for a vecotorized solution.

Example one:

```
first_arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
second_arr = [2, 4, 5, 11, 13]

result_arr = [6]
```

Example two:

```
first_arr = [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
second_arr = [14, 15, 22, 23, 24, 26, 30, 31, 32]

result_arr = [25, 26, 27, 33]
```

Comment: Yes, apologies. I will edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is a vectorized function-- only using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
def sliding_window_contains(first_arr, second_arr, lookback, contains):
    s = np.r_[False, np.in1d(first_arr, second_arr)]
    size = s.size - lookback, lookback + 1
    idx = np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(s, size, s.strides*2)[:,:-1].sum(1)>=contains
    return np.array(first_arr[lookback - 1:])[idx]
```

---

```
first_arr1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
second_arr1 = [2, 4, 5, 11, 13]
sliding_window_contains(first_arr1, second_arr1, 4, 3)
array([6])
```

---

```
first_arr2 = [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
second_arr2 = [14, 15, 22, 23, 24, 26, 30, 31, 32]
sliding_window_contains(first_arr2, second_arr2, 4, 3)
array([25, 26, 27, 33])
```

Comment: this works well on the test data but I get "IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 6008 but corresponding boolean dimension is 5992" when run on a live set @Onyambu

Comment: @Andy I am unable to tell why that is the case.  what is the length of `first_arr` in your case? You could debug the code to see where the problem lies. Note that the code is straightforward. ie arrange in a matrix form then sum the along the rows. ie [1,0,0,1,1] can be arranged as [[1,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,1,1]] and then sum. Then look for positions where sum >= 3.

Comment: first_arr is 6011, second_arr is 815

Comment: @Andy then you should have 6008 and not 5992. try stepping into the function. consider running `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided(s, size, s.strides*2)[:,:-1].sum(1).size` and see what you get

Comment: Thanks Onyambu, will do. The issue seems to occur when I change the lookback and contains parameters.

Comment: the issue seems to occur where the difference between the lookback value and the contains value is greater than 1. How can I handle that @Onyambu?

Comment: @Andy change `contains:` to `lookback-1:`. That should fix the issue

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import sliding_window_view

first_arr = [22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
second_arr = [14, 15, 22, 23, 24, 26, 30, 31, 32]

lookback = 4  # lookback length
contains = 3  # number of intersecting values

# pad the first array at the front (pad with a number that's
definitely not in second_arr)
farr = np.pad(
    first_arr,
    (lookback - contains, 0),
    "constant",
    constant_values=np.sum(np.abs(second_arr)) + 1
)

result_arr = [
    row[-1]
    for row in sliding_window_view(farr, lookback + 1)
    if len(np.intersect1d(row[:lookback], second_arr)) >= contains
]
```

This creates [sliding window view](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lib.stride_tricks.sliding_window_view.html) of the initial array and checks the number of [intersecting values](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.intersect1d.html). It still does contain a for loop, so there may be other NumPy vectorisations possible.